# Replace values in Excel columns from hashtable using Powershell

Tags: excel, powershell, hashtable

I have a table that has columns A,B,C,D,E in an xlsx file.
I'm able to import and replace data in the file using $Range.Find however I anticipate this file to quickly grow up to 200k rows. This method will no longer be feasible.

What I need is columns B and C have either "TRUE" or "FALSE". I need these replaced with "YES" or "NO". Additionally, column E will have numbers 1-4. Each of these will represent a string. I need to have these numbers replaced with their respective string.

Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Just one sheet? Are there formulas required, or could this be saved as a CSV and imported into PowerShell that way? If this doesn't need formulas (at least for the columns you are dealing with), and pasting un-formatted text into Excel is an option I would suggest converting it to CSV and manipulating data, then pasting it into the spreadsheet.

Comment: Yes. Its just a single sheet. Initially it starts with 3 sheets and various processing is done. The end result, before the actions listed above is applied, is a single sheet without any formulas, only plain text.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to convert it to CSV. I tried readily available scripts and modules but they take too long. Several minutes to import a 155 line Excel file. My end file is expected to have over 200k lines.

Comment: Look up Import-XLS on the MS script gallery, it'll do what you want I think